# Split dataset, stratify by Outcome and keep same patients in the same groups

Tags: r, machine-learning, split

Here is my dataset :

```
structure(list(PatientID = c("P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"P5", "P6"), LesionResponse = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), pyrad_tum_original_shape_LeastAxisLength = c(19.7842995242803, 
    15.0703960571122, 21.0652247652897, 11.804125918871, 27.3980336338908, 
    17.0584330264122, 4.90406343942677, 4.78480430022189, 6.2170232078547, 
    5.96309532740722, 5.30141540007441), pyrad_tum_original_shape_Sphericity = c(0.652056853392657, 
    0.773719977240238, 0.723869070051882, 0.715122964970338, 
    0.70796498824535, 0.811937882810929, 0.836458991713367, 0.863337931630415, 
    0.851654860256904, 0.746212862162174), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_firstorder_Skewness = c(0.367453961973625, 
    0.117673346718817, 0.0992025164349288, -0.174029385779302, 
    -0.863570016875989, -0.8482193060411, -0.425424618080682, 
    -0.492420174157913, 0.0105111292451967, 0.249865833210199), pyrad_tum_log.sigma.5.0.mm.3D_glcm_Contrast = c(0.376932105256115, 
    0.54885738172596, 0.267158344601612, 2.90094719958076, 0.322424096161189, 
    0.221356030145403, 1.90012334870722, 0.971638740404501, 0.31547550396399, 
    0.653999340294952), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_GrayLevelNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.154973213866752, 
    0.176128379241556, 0.171129002059539, 0.218343919352019, 
    0.345985943932352, 0.164905080489496, 0.104536489151874, 
    0.1280276816609, 0.137912385073012, 0.133420904484894), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaEmphasis = c(27390.2818110851, 
    11327.7931034483, 51566.7948885976, 7261.68702290076, 340383.536555142, 
    22724.7792207792, 45.974358974359, 142.588235294118, 266.744186046512, 
    1073.45205479452), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_LargeAreaLowGrayLevelEmphasis = c(677.011907073653, 
    275.281153810458, 582.131636238695, 173.747506476692, 6140.73990175018, 
    558.277670638306, 1.81042257642817, 4.55724031114589, 6.51794350173746, 
    19.144924585586), pyrad_tum_wavelet.LHH_glszm_SizeZoneNonUniformityNormalized = c(0.411899490603372, 
    0.339216399209913, 0.425584323452468, 0.355165782879786, 
    0.294934042125209, 0.339208410636982, 0.351742274819198, 
    0.394463667820069, 0.360735532720389, 0.36911240382811)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want here to split my datas into three sets :

- Train : 60%
- Validation and testing : 20% each.

As you can see, some rows correspond to the same patient. Imagine I have 127 unique patients with 1052 total rows and 156 features...

I must logically keep all the same patients in the same group to avoid overfitting...and I must stratify on the binary outcome 1-0.

I tried many codes like this one (I would prefer to have a loop for all this thing but nothing works) but in my sets, I have some rows missing for absolutely no reason. Second, I have common rows among my 3 sets of datas and don't know why...

```
set.seed(123)

# Get unique patient IDs
patient_ids <- unique(df$PatientID)

# Randomly assign patient IDs to training, validation, or testing group
patient_groups <- rep(c("train", "val", "test"), length.out = length(patient_ids))
patient_groups <- sample(patient_groups)

# Split data by patient group
train_patients <- patient_ids[patient_groups == "train"]
val_patients <- patient_ids[patient_groups == "val"]
test_patients <- patient_ids[patient_groups == "test"]

train_data <- df %>% filter(PatientID %in% train_patients) %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.6, replace = FALSE)
val_data <- df %>% filter(PatientID %in% val_patients) %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.5, replace = FALSE)
test_data <- df %>% filter(PatientID %in% test_patients) %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.5, replace = FALSE)

# Verify that all patients are included in only one group
all_patients <- c(train_patients, val_patients, test_patients)
stopifnot(length(unique(all_patients)) == length(patient_ids))

# Stratify the split based on LesionResponse
prop_train <- sum(train_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(train_data)
prop_val <- sum(val_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(val_data)
prop_test <- sum(test_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(test_data)

# Print proportions of positive LesionResponse in each group
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in training set:", round(prop_train, 2), "\n")
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in validation set:", round(prop_val, 2), "\n")
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in testing set:", round(prop_test, 2), "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you pair `slice_sample` and `replace = FALSE` together and there are not enough rows to fill desired sample size.

You could use `min` function to ensure sample size is limited by amount of rows available for each patient.

Replace everywhere you use slice_sample similar to this

```
slice_sample(n = min(n(), floor(0.6 * n())))
```

Edit: This is an alternate version with loop and `caret` library in mind

```
library(caret)

set.seed(123)

# Get unique patient IDs
patient_ids <- unique(df$PatientID)

# Stratify the patient IDs based on LesionResponse
stratified_patient_ids <- stratified(patient_ids, df$LesionResponse, size = 0.2, table = TRUE)

# Split the patient IDs into three sets: train, val, and test
train_patients <- sample(unlist(stratified_patient_ids[1:2]))
val_patients <- sample(unlist(stratified_patient_ids[3]))
test_patients <- sample(unlist(stratified_patient_ids[4]))

# Split data by patient group
train_data <- df[df$PatientID %in% train_patients, ]
val_data <- df[df$PatientID %in% val_patients, ]
test_data <- df[df$PatientID %in% test_patients, ]

# Verify that all patients are included in only one group
all_patients <- c(train_patients, val_patients, test_patients)
stopifnot(length(unique(all_patients)) == length(patient_ids))

# Stratify the split based on LesionResponse
prop_train <- sum(train_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(train_data)
prop_val <- sum(val_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(val_data)
prop_test <- sum(test_data$LesionResponse == "1") / nrow(test_data)

# Print proportions of positive LesionResponse in each group
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in training set:", round(prop_train, 2), "\n")
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in validation set:", round(prop_val, 2), "\n")
cat("Proportion of positive LesionResponse in testing set:", round(prop_test, 2), "\n")
```

This loop ensures patients are kept together in same group and split is stratified based on `LesionResponse` outcome.

Here we are also optimizing code by splitting data set into two or more parts based on specified proportion by usage of `caret` package, while also addressing issue with missing rows check.

Comment: hmm I don't understand...would it be more easy to make a loop to make the sets with at the same time patients in the same groups and stratified by the LesionResponse outcome ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with your idea of looping in mind. Note that you might still need to debug this based on your own needs, but this should give you a general idea of where to start

Comment: I'm ok with your code but don't you need to set seed and sample to make it with. hazard ?

Comment: Setting seed is a good idea to make results reproducible. Though `stratified` function from `caret` package already takes care of stratifying the data based on binary outcome `LesionResponse`. If you still want to use random sampling to further ensure data is split randomly, you can add `sample` function to the code. Example `set.seed(123)`  `train_patients <- sample(unlist(stratified_patient_ids[1:2]))`

Comment: `stratified` function is from `caret` package

Comment: ok I get it but I have always the same error message. Do you know what could be "x" and "setDT" ? I searched in help() function but found nothing... Okay I got it I did a "as.data.frame" and it works...a little. It just tells me that "Error in `[.data.table`(indt, , `:=`(temp_grp, do.call(paste, .SD)), .SDcols = group) : 
  .SDcols should be column numbers or names"